# Simple Python Search Spider, Page Ranker, and Visualizer

Tags: python, html, sqlite, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to crawl a web site to get all the anchor tags and picking the href using BeautifulSoup html parser.
Although, the algorithm creates a database, it does not parse the html. An error with print statement "Unable to retrieve or parse page" is shown. If i try again it shows "No retrieved HTML pages found".

I upgraded from python 2 to 3. I also deleted the previous Bs4 folder and downloaded a new one from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4. And unzipped it in same folder where the code is.

This is the import for the code

`import sqlite3`
`import urllib.error`
`import ssl`
`from urllib.parse import urljoin`
`from urllib.parse import urlparse`
`from urllib.request import urlopen`
`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`